# Create Setup Project in Visual Studio 2017 (with MSSQL Server Database)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, setup-project, sql-server-2017

I did a project using C# (Windows Form Application), and I used MSSQL Server 2017 for database operations. My project is as follows; the user selects a value from the listbox and presses the button for analysis. After this process, I perform a mathematical operation on the values ​​from the table and list the results on the DataGridView. So, the user will not do any action on the database, you can think of it as read only.

- What kind of problems can I experience when installing this project to the user?
- Do I need to install MSSQL Server to the user? I set it up on my own computer and I installed it on my computer and there was no problem, I have added a backup of my database in the MSSQL Server into my setup file. Is it enough to be this way?
- Will I have problems with database operations when I install it on another computer?
- Will I need to change the SQL connection clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, using SQL Server for this is extreme, to say the least. SQL Server is better for database-intensive applications, it requires setting up a lot of stuff on the computer and it's generally not used for client-side applications, although big desktop applications might use SQL Server Express (a downsized, free version) if they require so much performance.

I would suggest you to leave that aside and use SQL Server Express LocalDb (a `.mdb` file), which can be installed pretty easily; or you could even use SQLite which requires no installation.

Regarding your questions:

> What kind of problems can I experience when installing this project to the user?

You will probably run many issues, the SQL Server setup can fail due to thousands of different problems and uninstallation can very easily leave the system in a corrupt state.

> Do I need to install MSSQL Server to the user? I set it up on my own computer and I installed it on my computer and there was no problem, I have added a backup of my database in the MSSQL Server into my setup file. Is it enough to be this way?

If you wanted to use SQL Server, then yes, installation would be required.

> Will I have problems with database operations when I install it on another computer?

Assuming the installation went OK, not probably.

> Will I need to change the SQL connection clause?

Not really, using `Server= .\KnownServerInstanceName` would be enough to make it work always.

Comment: Hi, thank you for answer. This is my first project, so I'm a amateur. :) I have 200 thousand rows of data in my SQL Server table. How can I move all of this data from SQL Server to SQLite? And, of course, I have SQL statements that I encoded in my C # project. If I begin to use SQLite, will this code work again? So the languages ​​they use are the same?

Comment: @ImaNewCoder If you are that deep into the project, perhaps the best course of action is to just change to SQL Server LocalDB. ClickOnce (if you use it) can install it for you

Comment: If I use what you say, do I not need to install the user any MSSQL Server? And how do I change the SQL connection statement I coded?

Comment: @ImaNewCoder No, only SQL Server LocalDb which can be installed by ClickOnce if you use that, and copying the installer would be easy enough otherwise. Check here for connection strings: https://www.connectionstrings.com/sqlconnection/localdb-named-instance/

Comment: Hi again sir. I installed SQL Server Expression LocalDB 2017 and i moved my database in it. I connected my new database to my project. And it's extension is .mdf. Does this provide my requirement (I mean; can I run it with only the project setup without having any installation on other users' computers?). My connection string is; "Data Source=(localdb)\MyInstance;AttachDbFilename=C:\...\databasename.mdf;Initial Catalog=databasename;Integrated Security=True".

Answer (score 1):

If you are wanting to allow users on different computers use this program they will need access to the database. This can be done by either giving them the database or putting your database on server that can be accessed remotely.

> What kind of problems can I experience when installing this project to
>   the user?

There are a number of problems that could occur depending on different factors, however if you use a remote server for your database you will probably have less due to not knowing exactly how to access the database.

Understanding you may not have access to a remote server to put your database on, it might be easier to put your database file on the user's computer. Most likely the issues that stem from this are due to your database file location and your connection string mismatching. So if you do decide to download the database to the users computer most likely your errors will have to do with database file location.

> What kind of problems can I experience when installing this project to
>   the user? Do I need to install MSSQL Server to the user?

You will most likely only need to provide the user with the database file. The issue you might run into is if you give the user the database and put it on their computer you may run into the issue of an incorrect database location in respect to the connection string in you app.config.

> Is it enough to be this way? Will I have problems with
>   database operations when I install it on another computer? Will I need
>   to change the SQL connection clause?

Yes you will want to change the SQL connection clause if you download the database to the users computer unless you can garuntee the database is placed in the matching location as in the connection string.

> Will I have problems with database operations when I install it on
>   another computer?

You should not.

> Will I need to change the SQL connection clause?

For sure not if you put your database on a server. Perhaps if you download the database to the users computer.

**Side Note**

If you want to make the project portable and not have database on a server I recommend that you create a .mdf file (which is the file format used by Microsoft SQL Server. ) and you create a file in your project's debug folder(or where ever your .exe file is located) and call it DATABASE then place your .mdf into this file. Now change your connection string to find this database placed in the DATABASE folder from the current directory which will be that Debug folder of the project. This should take care of most of your issues because where the project goes so does the Database file.

Here is how you could set up your conString:

```
connectionString="data source={AppDir}\data\DATABASE\yourDataBaseName.mdf
```

In your code:

```
ConnectionStringSettings c = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[name];  



if (c == null)
{
    ... handle missing connection string ...
}
string fixedConnectionString = c.ConnectionString.Replace("{AppDir}", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
... use fixedConnectionString
```

this will always start out of the directory that your .exe is located.

P.S. If your using sql databases alot I highly recomend ssms which is SQL server management studio. It has made things much easier for me. Might help you too. :)